# Docker / how to determine link?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I wish to use the following docker [ivankrizsan/elastalert](https://hub.docker.com/r/ivankrizsan/elastalert/). I have docker of elasticsearch 5 installed (with name: elasticsearch)

In the guide line, its said: Requires a link to a Docker container running Elasticsearch using the "elasticsearchhost" alias.

So I did the following:

```
docker run --link "elasticsearch:elasticsearchhost" ivankrizsan/elastalert
```

and it says:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.
```

When I remove that link, and run just:

```
docker run ivankrizsan/elastalert
```

It doesn't find the elasticsearch port (Its looping this section:

```
while ! wget -O garbage_file ${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT} 2>/dev/null
do
    echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch..."
    rm -f garbage_file
    sleep 1
done
```

)

What I do wrong?

Comment: How `elasticsearch` container is started. Based on error message it has `--network=host` option?

Comment: @Lauri Yes, net=host

Comment: Any particular reason for that?

Comment: @Lauri We export port 9200 to other machines by doing that

Comment: You can just use `-p 9200:9200` to expose port 9200 to other machines. Otherwise you have to set the host machine's ip as `ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` environment variable. Not sure how handy that might be.

Comment: @Lauri: I remove net=host and add port: -9200:9200 (via ansible), and it is still not working.

Comment: are you able to link the container now?

Comment: @Lauri, no I encounter the same problem. I have the following definitions:     `    restart_policy: always
    pull: always
    state: reloaded ports:
    - 9200:9200
    expose:
    - 9200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you used --network=host when creating elasticsearch container.

Another issue that I noticed is using links, Linking containers is a legacy feature, and is being replaced by user defined networks. User defined networks will also give you an internal dns for service discovery.

To fix the issue first stop and remove elasticsearch container.

Create a user-defined network for your contianers:

```
sudo docker network create elastic
```

Start elasticsearch container:

```
sudo docker run -d --name elasticsearchhost -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" --network elastic docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2 elasticsearch
```

Verify elasticsearch is up:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'
```

If you have xpack enabled, You need to supply username and password:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'
```

elastic: default username

changeme: default password

In order to fix `Waiting for Elasticsearch...` you need to disable security plugin, or set username/password in elsatalert.

To disable security authentication in elasticsearch add the following line in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml`

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

And restart elasticsearch container.

To verify:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'
```

Start ivankrizsan/elastalert container:

```
sudo docker run -d --name elastalert --network elastic -e  ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearchhost -e ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200 ivankrizsan/elastalert
```

Please note environment variables via `-e` switch.

Comment: post `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`

Comment: @user2915097: When Im doing wget localhost:9200, I get --2017-03-09 10:15:32--  http://localhost:9200/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:9200... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

Comment: @MiddleWare try `curl 127.0.0.1:9200` from docker host, You should see node name and  info.

Comment: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: do `sudo docker logs -f elasticsearch` look for errors, and `sudo docker ps` make sure elasticsearch container is running.

Comment: Its running: [es] timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s
[es] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[es] started

Comment: The problem is your elasticsearch, Are you using the exact docker run command that I provided in the answer? `-e "http.host=0.0.0.0"` is the key part

Comment: I run exactly the command you write and when I do Xget it writes: 
{
  "name" : "fC3Pvi4",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "g91WduI8R8eHu_Y8XvX2tg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "f9d9b74",
    "build_date" : "2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

But it still writes: Waiting for Elasticsearch...

Comment: Okey your elasticsearch is fine now, you are failing because of xpack security on elsaticsearch. see updated answer

Comment: unknown setting [xpack.security.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings

Comment: I actually tested it out myself, How are you putting that line in elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: Like you wrote, the error indicates that it got the parameter correctly.

Comment: thats weired because we are using the same docker images version ... just remove that line ,restart the container and try `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'` if you get cluster name response, leave xpack part and move forward to the rest.

Comment: What do you mean by and move forward to the rest?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I did before, and it gives me the Waiting for Elasticsearch... message